# how to use plugins in pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple question!

I installed a wordpress plugin (like [that](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/)).
It prints some links .. when we called it: `<?php echo oscimp_getproducts(3); ?>`

Now, I want to print that links in a page, called "Our market".

How can I placed that code into my page (where is my page php code? and how can I edit it?)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you unsure of how to edit a template? Or are you just unsure of exactly which file to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a [Custom Page Template?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) I would do this, then stick the PHP code you shared above in the template file. If you're feeling adventurous and know a bit about PHP, you could also try creating a [Shortcode.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Comment: Upvote from me -- a custom page template is the most straightforward way to create a page with custom code (like calls to functions your plugin provides).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to include arbitrary PHP in a given post/page is to use a plugin like [Shortcode Exec PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/), especially if you're not comfortable with PHP programming.